# blueimp's fileupload angular version, binding custom callback

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, callback, blueimp

I'm using the angularJS version (V2.1.2) of Blueimp's famous fileupload JQuery plugin with the PHP backend. Very nice piece of code.
I customized it with some additional form controls and selector, as well as a custom UploadHandler by extending the provided class, in order to record stuff in a database.
Everything works fine so far.

However, I have trouble binding a custom callback to the 'fileuploadsubmit' event. It's described in https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options for JQuery, but I can't seem to make it work with the AngularJS implementation. The aim would be for me to submit the additionnal field "doctypes[]" that I tied to each individual upload.

Here is the extract of the added field:

```
                <td class="type" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                <label data-ng-switch-when="false" data-ng-show="!file.error">
                    <select data-ng-model="docTypeId" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in documentTypes | orderBy:'name'" required="required" name="doctypes[]">
                        <option value="" selected>Document type</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label data-ng-switch-default><!-- here, find a way to display the value submited to the plugin. {{file.doctypes}} is not defined -->
                </label>
            </td>
```

Note: the documentTypes comes from my angularJS app, it is currently statically defined in the main controller.

So this additionnal field is properly posted to the uploadhandler, but I would like the plugin to receive it, and send it back in the JSON response, so as to change the layout and fix the selector to the value it had before the upload.

I consider myself a beginner in AngularJS, so maybe I don't have a clear and detailed grasp on the technical bits on how to do this properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With further research and testing, I was able to properly bind the event in my controller like so: $scope.$on('fileuploadsubmit', function (event, files) { ...do stuff... });
However I cannot access attributes from the fileupload directive. I have the feeling that I should start digging around the emit/broadcast events of the fileupload directive's scope... passing the $rootScope in my controller didn't help.

Comment: Using this module: [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) might save you some hassle and make your code simpler. Have a look at the readme file, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. However I must say that although your implementation is easier to follow, I quite like the hardened security of Blueimp's one and the multiple options to customize it.